# 3D Harmonics library on windows - pyshtools failed building wheel + fatal error with fftw3.lib

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, fortran, gfortran

We need a tool to work with 3D-Harmonics and we've come across https://github.com/SHTOOLS/SHTOOLS - which fits all of our needs, but could not be installed properly on our windows computers (as it's intended for linux\osx).

When we tried to run `pip install .` in the directory SHTOOLS-3.3 (we use anaconda for managing packages and it includes pip), we at first got an error saying that we need a Fortran compiler (gfortran) - which we fixed by installing gcc with `conda install -c r gcc`. Afterwards, we got an error saying we need to install visual C++ compiler - which we downloaded as suggested from https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44266.

Alas, running the command again, this time from the visual C++ 2008 command prompt, we still get a fatal error and are still stuck with installing the library.

Some of the errors we get:

```
could not find library 'fftw3' in directories ['build\\temp.win-amd64-2.7']
could not find library 'm' in directories ['build\\temp.win-amd64-2.7']
could not find library 'lapack' in directories ['build\\temp.win-amd64-2.7']
could not find library 'blas' in directories ['build\\temp.win-amd64-2.7']
```

Followed by

```
LINK: fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'fftw3.lib'
```

and

```
Failed building wheel for pyshtools
```

The full output of the installation attempt can be found [here](http://pasteboard.co/9hXwqA8Ut.png) and [here](http://pasteboard.co/9hYPi8BYM.png).

We've tried to download the lib files of the FFTW3, LAPACK and BLAS libraries but couldn't build them properly.

We would appreciate any help (suggesting a similar library that is compatible with windows \ helping with the install of SHTOOlS).

Comment: "We've tried to download the lib files of the FFTW3, LAPACK and BLAS libraries but couldn't build them properly." What does that mean?

Comment: I've downloaded the precompiled dll's from http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html and made them into lib and tried to  include them (plus lib files from LAPACK and BLAS) in some directory that is scanned by mingw - but couldn't (first time handling such problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shame when you find something ready to go but very time consuming to make it work on windows. My advice would be avoid the hazzle of installing that non-ready-to-go-on-windows library and just looking for another alternative, there are few ones dealing with spherical harmonics. What about this one? [pyspharm](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyspharm)

Also, posting an issue in the library's [github issues](https://github.com/SHTOOLS/SHTOOLS/issues) could speed it up things.